# Plot the integral of a given interval around the position of x

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to plot the integration of a function with intervals around the position x.

I tried this with scipy.integrate.quad and scipy.integrate.cumtrapz, but none of them seemed to work. I thought this should be a pretty common task, but I could not find any sample code that could help me. The code below was an attempt that I tried to make work, but it won't return a useful result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

x = np.linspace(0, 3, num=1000)
def f(v):
    f=np.cos(np.pi*v)+1
    return f
def y_int(v):
    y_int = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(f(v), x, initial=0)
    return y_int
a=0.5
plt.plot(x, y_int(x+a)-y_int(x-a), 'r-')
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I switched to using `scipy.integrate.quad` since `cumtrapz` was causing issues over zero. Notice the ternary condition to give the `initial = 0` logic that `cumtrapz` provides.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

x = np.linspace(0, 3, num = 1000)
a = 0.5
f = lambda v: np.cos(np.pi * v) + 1

def y_int(v):
    integral = scipy.integrate.quad(f, v - a if v > a else 0, v + a)
    return integral[0]

plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b-')
plt.plot(x, np.array(map(y_int, x)), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Original

I reformatted/tweaked your code a little so I could work with values a little easier to validate with, like making your interval 0 to 2pi. I also removed your tolerance interval for checking purposes and you I believe you made a mistake in calling "v" "x" in the `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` function. Here it is cleaned up:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, num = 1000)

def f(v):
    f=np.cos(np.pi * v)
    return f

def y_int(v):
    y_int = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(f(v), v, initial=0)
    return y_int

plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b-') #plot the function from 0 to 2pi
plt.plot(x, y_int(x), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

This produces what I would expect the cumulative area under the function to look like since it zeros itself out at intervals of pi/3 and since the area double every (2/3)pi.

Here is your code cleaned up a little, and also ranging from 1 to 4 (with interval being 0 to 3, there's something about the x interval crossing over to negative with the initial being set to 0 is giving odd results):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

x = np.linspace(1, 4, num = 1000)
a = 0.5

def f(v):
    f=np.cos(np.pi * v) + 1
    return f

def y_int(v):
    y_int = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(f(v), v, initial=0)
    return y_int

plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b-')
plt.plot(x, y_int(x + a) - y_int(x - a), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks better already. Something still seems to be wrong with the result. Since f(v) is always >0, the integral of any interval can never be <0, also the resulting integral does not change when I change the y-offset of f(v). I am not sure how to make sense of this behaviour from the cumtrapz function.

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect, you had the "v" and "x" correct originally. Shift the range from 1 to 4 instead and the plot looks more reasonable. Something about crossing zero I will have to think more about. I will update my answer as well.

Comment: ^ I meant the x and y in the cumtrapz function.

Comment: Updated to use `quad` instead of `cumtrapz`. Hopefully either solution will work for you.